# How to figure the actual class when java.lang.ClassCastException occurs?

Tags: java, jaxb

Is it possible to figure out at all?

The runtime information should be available; otherwise, Java shouldn't be able to detect the problem.

Here the the snippet:

```
        m_jaxbCxt = JAXBContext.newInstance("generated");
        m_unMarshaller = m_jaxbCxt.createUnmarshaller();
        Model model = (Model)m_unMarshaller.unmarshal(new File(xmlName));
```

The exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast to generated.Model
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just log in console the object's class by object.getClass() where You are getting ClassCastException

Comment: I did try.  It gave me what the exception said, "javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement".

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the question, the answer is in the exception text. It's telling you that the object, which of of type `javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement`, can't be cast to `generated.Model`. So, the actual class is that `JAXBElement` class.

Comment: So, what is your question? The error message says you are trying to cast a `javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement` object to the type `Model`. Isn't that exactly what you wanted to know?

Comment: I was expecting that m_unMarshaller.unmarshal(new File(xmlName)) returned me an instance of Model.  And so I thought javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement was just a parent of "some class" that m_unMarshaller.unmarshal() returned.  Hence, I was looking for the actual child class.  But it turned out that javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement was indeed the actual child class.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the reference in a generic `Object` and inspect it at runtime with a debugger.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `JAXBIntrospector.getValue(Object)` on the result of the `unmarshal` operation.  This will unwrap the `JAXBElement` if there was one.

Answer (score 1):

If it's for debugging purposes, then inspecting the Object in a debbugger, like stated in another answer, is good.

However, if you need to check at runtime if an object is of a given type before casting it, you can use the `instanceof` operator:

```
Object object = m_unMarshaller.unmarshal(new File(xmlName));
Model model;
if(object instanceof Model) {
    model = (Model) object;
}
```